# Extended Displays on T430s with 4338 docking station

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, display, multiple-monitors, dvi

I have a t430 notebook with NVidia Optimus and according to this post here https://support.lenovo.com/en/en/solutions/migr-76617 I should be able to extend my display with at least 2 more monitors. My display settings correctly identify all 4 displays that I have connected right now: 1 laptop display, 1 VGA monitor, and 2 x DVI monitors but I only can use 2 displays at once (the t430s's display and another "random" monitor).

- [detected displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRCEI.jpg)
- [thinkpad graphics device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsdgx.jpg)
- [my current cable setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9v5m.jpg)

If I pull out one of the DVI monitors, then, another one will take its place an so on, but not more than 2 displays at once.

What can I do to have at least 3 displays (the laptop's display and 2 more monitors)?

Comment: This is hardware limitation by motherboard chipset. The easier way if you use USB docking stations (I have a Dell D3100 station, can connect 3 monitors to it, also can use laptop internal and hdmi+dp ports same time (6 displays same time)).

Comment: So you are saying that I can't use more than 2 displays with my current setup because of the motherboard chipset of my t430s? Why does the Lenovo support page say otherwise?

Comment: If you use Diplayport -Displayport (monitor must connected with displayport cable, or via ACTIVE displayport adapter), you can setup the configuration mentoined in the lenovo support page. But VGA,DVI, HDMI used to share the channel, so only one (at most 2 when you disable internal display (enable 1st external, extend, disable internal, enable 2nd external)) display can be used. The limitation: Only 2 of any of these can be used same time: VGA, HDMI, Internal panel, DVI. These connectors connected directly to motherboard chipset/cpu, so its a hardware limitation. DP comes on separated lane.

Comment: + NVIDIA optimus not counts in this case, the video outputs wired to the integrated graphic (intel xxx).

Comment: I knew it has to do something with the DisplayPort but the Lenovo support documentation was confusing so I wasn't sure. None of my monitors has DP input so because I didn't know about the "active" part of the DP, yesterday already bought this https://www.ebay.com/itm/3in1-Display-Port-DP-Male-to-HDMI-VGA-DVI-Adapter-Cable-Converter-for-PC-Laptop/162122488051 and I'm pretty sure it's not activated. I guess this is exactly what I need: https://www.amazon.com/Cable-Matters-Plated-DisplayPort-Adapter/dp/B00EDT01TO. Thanks for clearing things up for me, at least now I know what I need to do/buy

Comment: Out of frustration, I also bought this https://www.ebay.com/itm/USB-DVI-To-VGA-HDMI-Multiple-Monitor-External-Graphics-Card-Display-Adapter-XP/173073865661 and I guess I could use it on top of the Lenovo monitor + regular DVI + Active DP so I will end up with a total of 4 displays.

Comment: I'll write a summary answer soon. Your adapter is passive, active adapters a bit expensive. With this adapter, its belong to 2 monitor limit, because when you use passive adapter, displayport use the hdmi's sync, so hdmi will disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IGPU can handle 2 of these ports same time:

- Internal display
- VGA port
- DVI port
- HDMI port
- Displayport, if passive converter cable connected (like DP to hdmi/vga/dvi cable or adapter)

You can use the 3 display if the 3rd one connected to displayport, and
the monitor connected with displayport-displayport cable, or if your monitor
has no displayport, then you need to use ACTIVE displayport to hdmi/dvi/vga adapter. If you have more display ports, you can get 4th display keeping
this rule.

Active adapters looks like this: 
[https://www.amazon.com/Accell-Displayport-HDMI-Active-Adapter/dp/B01AYQ5APE/ref=sr_1_2_sspa?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1519688175&sr=1-2-spons&keywords=displayport+to+hdmi+active&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01AYQ5APE)

But this cable is passive:
[https://www.amazon.com/Cable-Matters-Gold-Plated-DisplayPort/dp/B004C9P9TM/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1519687969&sr=1-1-spons&keywords=displayport+to+hdmi&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004C9P9TM)

Update: Related to OP comments, the linked USB to VGA adapter is fine, but only good for get picture on monitor, do some non-vga intensive task, ex browsing. Forget gaming etc, because the adapter is fully separated from IGPU and the Optimus.

Comment: https://www.ebay.com/itm/Active-DisplayPort-DP-to-DVI-Video-Audio-Adapter-ATI-Eyefinity-4k-Black/201705351626 I guess this is the cheapest Active DP to DVI  can get and buying two of them will get me using 4 displays at once using the current configuration (lenovo t430s + 4338 docking station)

Comment: This adapter will fine for you. Mine looks like same just with HDMI.

Comment: Welcome. I ran into same problem some years ago, and googled days while somewhere I found some useful info about the active-passive adapters.